# NHibernate: second level cache expiration

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, second-level-cache

We are using Nhibernate and second level cache (non strict read write). When profiling the app using NH Profiler, I can see that data are requested once. But if the web app is idle, after a few minutes, at first request, data are requested again... Is there some expiration date/timeout on the cache? What should I do to prevent the cache from being cleared?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using SysCache :

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="syscache" type="NHibernate.Caches.SysCache.SysCacheSectionHandler,NHibernate.Caches.SysCache" />
  </configSections>

  <syscache>
    <cache region="foo" expiration="500" priority="4" />
    <cache region="bar" expiration="300" priority="3" />
  </syscache>
</configuration>
```

Comment: it works fine, thanks. Just one more question: do you know the default expiration delay?

Comment: I believe the default is 300 (5 minutes). Read this in NHibernate in Action.

Comment: How do I set this expiration timeout through the fluent configuration?